# How to create an array by specifying diagonal values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, diagonal

I have an array like below:

```
  poles = numpy.array([[-1+1j], [-1-1j], [-2+3j], [-2-3j]])
```

Its shape is (4,1).

When I use the numpy.diag like below:

```
LA = numpy.diag(poles)
```

The output is `[-1.+1.j]` while I'm expecting to see a diagonal matrix.
Can someone explain what is going on and what should be done to see a diagonal matrix?
I also tried to change the shape to (1,4) but the result didn't change.

Comment: What are you expecting? `np.diag` will take the diagonal values of your array, which there is only one item since one of your axes is only length 1.

Comment: @busybear. I expected to get a diagonal array (4*4 matrix) where the diagonal elements are the elements of poles and all other elements to be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `np.fill_diagonal`. This will set the diagonal values of an array. You'll have to create the array first:

```
arr = np.zeros((4, 4), dtype=np.complex64))
np.fill_diagonal(arr, poles)
```

`arr` is now:

```
array([[-1.+1.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j, -1.-1.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j, -2.+3.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j, -2.-3.j]], dtype=complex64)
```

---

`np.diagonal`, on the other hand, retrieves the values in the diagonal. Output of `np.diagonal(arr)` is:

```
array([-1.+1.j, -1.-1.j, -2.+3.j, -2.-3.j], dtype=complex64)
```

In your example, you are retrieving the diagonal of `poles`, which only has one value in the diagonal since one of the axes is only length 1.